kmscon get black (no signal loss) screen after 5 seconds
I have installed
sudo apt-get install kmscon

It's working when I starting my computer. My computer is a single board computer. I have connected the HDMI output to my TV.
Once the kmscon is started, I can see the login prompt for about 5 seconds, then the text goes black. The whole screen goes black. But it's not a connection loss. It's more like the kmscon stop re-print the text. If I press a button on my remote control, e.g volume or settings, then the login prompt appears again, but then disappear after 5 seconds once again.
One thing I have notice, if I continuously increase and decrease the volume on the TV, then the screen stays active. Then the text from kmscon won't go black. So I don't know if this is a TV setting for the HDMI, or something I can control from my single board computer?
Notice that I'm missing the file /etc/kmscon/kmscon.conf. I don't know why.
The screen goes into some kind of "sleep" mode, but it's not really sleep mode. It can easily be awaken by touching the buttons of the remote control.
My thought is that the kmscon not sending signals to the TV and tell it to stay awake.
This happens to when I call
weston

After 5 minutes exactly, then the screen goes black and lose its HDMI connection. The solution is
weston --idle-time=0

Then the screen stays alive. That's why I'm thinking that perhaps kmscon having the same issue as weston had.
